# is it possible to use custom image verified from organization in aks cluster using terraform?

Tags: terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

I am trying to figure out to use custom node image in AKS cluster using the terraform but i could not get any relatable resource which i can use as a reference. is there any way we can use or currently custom image is not supported in aks cluster ?.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK AKS as of today does not support custom images.

Check out [AKS-Engine](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine) when you want to use [custom images](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/blob/master/examples/custom-image.json).

I dont know why you want to use a custom image but maybe the preview feature [CustomNodeConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/custom-node-configuration) can help you. Here you can modify kubelet, OS and other settings.